# Почему выражение не работает?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('input:checkbox:checked:enabled').css({
  'width': '30px',
  'height': '30px'
 });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Работает

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input:checkbox:checked:enabled').css({
    'width': '30px',
    'height': '30px'
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" checked>
<input type="checkbox" checked disabled>
```

**UPDATE:** `$(document).ready()` означает, что функцию надо выполнить в тот момент, когда документ загрузился. Чтобы выполнить её тогда, когда меняется состояние чекбокса, нужно использовать `$('input:checkbox').change()`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input:checkbox').change(function(event) {
    var size = $(this).prop('checked') ? '30px' : 'auto';
    $(this).css({
      'width': size,
      'height': size
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox">
```

Comment: Аааа, ну так работает(Я просто думал, что при таком вызове скрипт должен срабатывать, когда мы нажимаем на наш checkbox и переводим его в активное состояние)...

Answer (score 1):

$ is not defined = не подключен jquery